# Node JS issue with SSL pfx file

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, certificate, pfx

when I run my server.js, I have this issue :

```
node:internal/tls/secure-context:277
      context.loadPKCS12(toBuf(pfx), toBuf(passphrase));
              ^

Error: unsupported
    at configSecureContext (node:internal/tls/secure-context:277:15)
    at Object.createSecureContext (node:_tls_common:117:3)
    at Server.setSecureContext (node:_tls_wrap:1354:27)
    at Server (node:_tls_wrap:1218:8)
    at new Server (node:https:74:3)
    at Object.createServer (node:https:112:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/nodeserver/server.js:21:27)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)

Node.js v18.14.2
```

I run this command in order to see what's wrong but I can't tell :

```
openssl pkcs12 -info -in ssl/pfxFile.pfx -noout
```

Here is the output of the command :

```
MAC: sha1, Iteration 1024
MAC length: 20, salt length: 20
PKCS7 Encrypted data: pbeWithSHA1And40BitRC2-CBC, Iteration 1024
Certificate bag
Certificate bag
PKCS7 Data
Shrouded Keybag: pbeWithSHA1And3-KeyTripleDES-CBC, Iteration 1024
```

I tried to do the pfx file twice, but same issue each time, I tried without password, I don't know what could block this, I updated Node and now I can't start my server.

Is there a change to Node that alters something with the certificates ?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try switching to a lower LTS node version. I've had the same issue today, going from 18.14 LTS to 16.19 LTS solved it. As of today people are still having [the same issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/40672).

Comment: Update: you might wanna try and create a new certificate file, this should work as well

Comment: Have a look here https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/40672#issuecomment-1203043462

Answer (score 2):

Run your server with `NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider`, like this:
`NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider node server.js`

For a detailed walkthrough, check out my article: [Read the full article here](https://medium.com/@JorgeSantanaDeveloper/navigating-the-node-js-unsupported-error-with-pfx-certificates-in-httpagent-341937a431f2)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot. My project is using angular framework. Update scripts command in package.json. It works well.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && ng serve --proxy-config xxx.js"
}
```